# Unable to concate the integer to the xpath and is not able to find it

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, calendar, concatenation

```
for i in range (1,6):
   col = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

  for j in range (1,7):
     xpath_string = ('/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/**tr[{0}]**/**td[{1}]**'.format(str(j), str(i)))
     day = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_string)
     B = day.text
     print(B)

     if (Date == B):
        path_string = ('/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/**tr[{0}]**/**td[{1}]**'.format(str(j), str(i)))
        say = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path_string)
        say.click()
        break
```

**TypeError:**

> Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is
>   not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

It is showing this type of error so please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the purpose of `**` in your xpath, they are not valid xpath expression. Following code line should be changed as below:

```
xpath_string = '/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[{1}]'
               .format(j,i)



path_string = '/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[{1}]'
              .format(j,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass the xpath directly into driver.find_element_by_xpath() rather than formatting it as a string first?

I envision it would look something like this:

```
    day = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[{1}]')
```

Comment: @RiteshJain could you possible share any of the HTML that you are trying to navigate with Selenium? Perhaps there is another method of driver.find_element_by_{property} that you could give a shot?
Also as @yong mentioned in his answer above, I don't believe  `**` is valid in an xPath. I have edited my answer to reflect that.